# Изменение названия кнопки по клике

Tags: java

Не могу найти ответа. Необходимо сделать изменение названия кнопки по клику на неё же.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GUI_Main extends Frame{

    //Конструктор размещает три кнопки
    GUI_Main (String title){
        super(title);

        //Формирование кнопок
        Button hanzel = new Button("Ганзель");
        Button and = new Button("и");
        Button gretel = new Button("Гретель");

        //Установка Layout-менеджера для размещения кнопок в линейку
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Добавление кнопок к фрейму
        add(hanzel);
        add(and);
        add(gretel);

        //Добавление прослушивателя событий для окна - WindowListener
        addWindowListener(new MainWindowLauscher());

        //Регистрация ActionListener для кнопки
        //Каждый раз создаётся новыый экземпляр.
        //Однако экземпляр можно использовать неоднократно.
        ActionListener listener = new MainActionLauscher();
        hanzel.addActionListener(listener);
        and.addActionListener(listener);
        gretel.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //Объявление и создание экземпляра класса
        GUI_Main window = new GUI_Main("GUI с обработкой событий");
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Класс MainWindowLauscher
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

```
//Определение собственных классов Adapter и Listener
//как внутренних классов класса GUI_Main
public class MainWindowLauscher extends WindowAdapter{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        //Выход из программы
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Класс MainActionLauscher. Ругается на Button.setLabel("");

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainActionLauscher implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Изменение название кнопки
        Button.setLabel("asdasd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainActionLausher` сделать внутренним классом в `GUIMain`, тогда переменные будут общими и `имякнопки.setLabel(".....");`
Правда это вариант на три разных слушателя, сделанных внутренними классами, чтобы между этими классами были видимости переменных, по одному на каждую кнопку. Чтобы был один класс копать надо в сторону `ActionListener(this)`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class GUI_Main extends Frame{
//Объявление переменных вынесено из конструктора, чтобы они были видны    внутреннему классу слушателя(ей)
    Button hanzel;
    Button and;
    Button gretel;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    //Объявление и создание экземпляра класса
    GUI_Main window = new GUI_Main("GUI с обработкой событий");
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}

//Конструктор размещает три кнопки
GUI_Main (String title){
    super(title);

    //Формирование кнопок
    hanzel = new Button("Ганзель");
    and = new Button("и");
    gretel = new Button("Гретель");

    //Установка Layout-менеджера для размещения кнопок в линейку
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Добавление кнопок к фрейму
    add(hanzel);
    add(and);
    add(gretel);

    //Добавление прослушивателя событий для окна - WindowListener
    addWindowListener(new MainWindowLauscher());

    //Регистрация ActionListener для кнопки
    //Каждый раз создаётся новыый экземпляр.
    //Однако экземпляр можно использовать неоднократно.
    hanzel.addActionListener(new MainActionLauscherHanzel());
    and.addActionListener(new MainActionLauscherAnd());
    gretel.addActionListener(new MainActionLauscherGretel());
}


//Слушатель для кнопки henzel
class MainActionLauscherHanzel implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Изменение название кнопки
        hanzel.setLabel("newHenzel");
    }
}
//Слушатель для кнопки and
class MainActionLauscherAnd implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Изменение название кнопки
        and.setLabel("newAnd");
    }
}
//Слушатель для кнопки gretel
class MainActionLauscherGretel implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Изменение название кнопки
        gretel.setLabel("newGretel");
    }
}
public class MainWindowLauscher extends WindowAdapter{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        //Выход из программы
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё понял.

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно могу ошибаться, но как у тебя определяется, какая именно кнопка нажата и к какой именно код выполнять?
На javascript подобная конструкция используется:

```
if(evt.target.equals(btnYellowBackground))
{
  setBackground(Color.yellow);
}
```

А у тебя обращение идет к Button, который не является абстрактным классом, насколько я знаю. Может в этом и есть ошибка?
P.S. Сижу с работы, проверить не могу, так что только общие размышления)